# EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AgGridNg2

Tags: typescript, angular, ag-grid

Why [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CcWFopZAgRjrCL3ZFmyC) on TypeSctipt with ag-grid isn't work?

There is error in console:

```
EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AgGridNg2
```

Code of cars.ts with poblem line:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {CarsService} from './cars_service'

@Component({
  selector: 'cars',
  bindings: [CarsService]
})
@View({
  template: `
      <ag-grid-ng2 id="cars" class="ag-fresh"
        [column-defs]="columnDefs" [row-data]="rowData">
      </ag-grid-ng2>
  `,

  ////////////////////////////////////
  // Problem at this line
  ////////////////////////////////////
  directives: [ag.grid.AgGridNg2]

})
export class Cars {

  private columnDefs: Object[];
  private rowData: Object[];

  constructor(service: CarsService) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
      { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
      { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
    ];

    service.getCars().subscribe(
    (res: Response) => {
      this.rowData = res.json();
      //console.log(this.rowData);
      // TODO: Refresh table
    });
  }
}
```

Must I import AgGridNg2 or not and how to do it? Or maybe current version of Angular2 Beta is broken?

Comment: This is caused by Angular update. Use Angular beta.0 version, and don't use minified Angular beta.1 version. This code form plunker is outdated, try to find newer version or rewrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at your plunkr. In beta versions, `angular2/angular2` is now `angular2/core`.

That said, it seems that you don't correctly initialize ag-grid. You should try something like that:

```
ag.grid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular2({ core: core });

bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_BINDINGS,
    ROUTER_BINDINGS,
    bind(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT).toValue(App),
    bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)
]);
```

and remove this block from your `index.html` file:

```
System.import("angular2/angular2").then(function(ng2) {
  ag.grid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular2(ng2);
});
```

Here is a sample of use of ag-grid with TypeScript: https://github.com/helix46/ag-grid-angular2-beta-ts. Here is the file regarding configuration: https://github.com/helix46/ag-grid-angular2-beta-ts/blob/master/src/boot.ts.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry