# Table plugin for angular2

Tags: angular

Is there any table plugin for angular 2.I am new to angular2 and I have to use a table to display json data. http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-table/ is what i found when googled but it is unclear on how to use.

Comment: The docs look pretty detailed. I think your first step would be to work through the tutorials on the [angular.io](https://angular.io) site and get an understanding of the basics first. Then you should be able to apply what you've learned to `ng2-table`

Comment: @SnareChops Thnx.I'll try

Comment: My recomendation would be to go with PrimeNG Datatable, too good, easy to use and paid customization  provided

Comment: valor-software sucks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkout PrimeNG DataTable, it is a native Angular2 component.

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could have a look at AgGridNg2. Here is a sample of use in this question:

- [EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AgGridNg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893234/exception-no-directive-annotation-found-on-aggridng2/)
- https://github.com/helix46/ag-grid-angular2-beta-ts

Hope it helps you,
Thierry